# How to convert GMT time to Local time?

Tags: javascript, datetime

In my application i am getting GMT hour, I want to convert it into Local one.
For example

```
var dateTime = "10:18:00"; //this am getting as GMT
//these below what i want hour and minute separated with locale time zone 
var hour = '15';
var minute = '48';
```

I want to convert it as local i.e if it is india then IST or if any other country then that country's standard time(Locale time). How to achieve this ?

Comment: Are you getting the datetime object?

Comment: Unless said time is always "today" (and you never have any times between midnight and 3 am, roughly), you **need** to get the date along with the time to properly handle DST and timezone changes. Also, you probably want/need to show which local date it is (in many instances, a timezone shift will mean a different date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `localHour` using `getTimezoneOffset()/60`. This is a very hacky way of doing it since you don't have the entire `Date` object for GMT.

```js
var dateTime = "10:18:00"; // GMT
var hour = dateTime.split(':')[0];
var minute = dateTime.split(':')[1];

var date = new Date(); // UTC
var localHour = hour - date.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
var localMinute = (localHour%1) * 60;

localHour = Math.floor(localHour);
localMinute += parseInt(minute);
if (localMinute >= 60) {
    localHour += Math.floor(localMinute/60);
    localMinute %= 60;
}

localHour %= 24;

console.log('local hour:', localHour);
console.log('local minute:', localMinute);
```

Comment: Can you check this for your use case?